# what is best way to figure out the arm pipeline architecture?

Tags: architecture, arm, pipeline

To optimize arm's assembly code, I found several documents such as arm's reference manual, technical manual, etc.

I expected to find simple pipeline-diagram like below.
[image]

However, through the manual, I counldn't find any diagrams nor description about the pipeline.

When I google, I can find some informations, but it is not enough, or not latest version.

Also, for the reliability, I want to get correct information from official document.

Is there any document that has correct & latest information of arm's pipeline architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the Software Optimization Guide for the core you are using, e.g. [Cortex A-72 Software Optimization Guide](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/uan0016/a/).  Page 6 has a diagram similar to the one in your question.

Note that lower-level details are likely to be proprietary, so if you need more information than what's in the guide, you will probably have to reverse engineer it by experimentation, or find someone else who has done so.  For cores designed by vendors other than Arm (e.g. Apple), even the basic pipeline structure may be proprietary.